# How do I match up two lists and only change the second in each pair?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I’m trying to make a Python plugin to automate adding HTML attributes to hyperlinks that fulfil certain criteria for footnotes (in ebooks) – for example, if it’s superscript, if it’s a number in a square or round bracket… so far so good and I’ve managed to add the attributes using Beautiful Soup for these conditions.

There are many footnote pairs in different ebooks. Ebooks are all made differently (so the footnotes don't necessarily all have the same class, for example). Each footnote number has an URL with a fragment identifier that is bidirectionally linked to another link with a corresponding ID to help the reader navigate.

For example:

```
// on chapter.xhtml

Footnote 1 <a id="fn1" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#rfn1">[1]</a>
Footnote 2 <a id="fn2" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#rfn2">[2]</a>

1. <a id="rfn1" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#fn1">1.</a> Footnote 1
2. <a id="rfn2" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#fn2">2.</a> Footnote 2
```

Desired result - but the returning links can appear anywhere in the ebook which is why it's useful to automate this process:

```
Footnote 1 <a id="fn1" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#rfn1">[1]</a>
Footnote 2 <a id="fn2" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#rfn2">[2]</a>

1. <a id="rfn1" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#fn1" role="doc-backlink">1.</a> Footnote 1
2. <a id="rfn2" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#fn2" role="doc-backlink">2.</a> Footnote 2
```

Now I wish to add an HTML attribute to all the links that have the job of returning back to the initial link in the pair. These will always be the links in the footnote pair that come second in the ebook (but their identifier could be named anything.) However there are many footnotes and I’m struggling to do a matching exercise.

So a few questions which I’d really appreciate some help with:

How do I find the fragment identifier of every footnote link?

How do I find the ID of every footnote link?

How do I compare the fragment identifiers and IDs?

How do I then add an HTML attribute to only the second occurrence in the ebook in each footnote pair?

I've tried nested for loops but I'm not actually sure how to achieve this. Currently I'm finding all the links using Beautiful Soup and, if they satisfy certain criteria, adding the relevant attributes using Beautiful Soup.

There are multiple chapters (xhtml files) in the ebooks so I'm hoping this won't affect the outcome of the plugin.

I’m completely new to this, so thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you share a part of the HTML code with us?

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- sure, I've shared a part.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't get what exacly you want to do....   
Could you provide one example solution for your problem? :/ So the HTML result/outcome you want

Could be that I don't understand it due to my bad english skills... :D

Comment: No problem - thanks for trying to help! Basically I've provided sample HTML for the footnotes. #rfn1 in the first link matches the id rfn1 in the footnote itself below it, and #rfn2 in the second link matches the id rfn2 in the footnote below it. I want to somehow add the attribute to the returning links (the footnotes below) but that means I have to get the IDs, compare and match, and add the attribute to the second link? Hope that makes sense. As it's an automatic tool, I don't always know the IDs of the footnotes so I'd like the tool to be able to detect and match them.

Comment: Sorry, I now understand what you meant by HTML outcome I want - I've added that above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption**: Footnotes always come second.

We'll iterate over all the links in a page, trying to see if each link contains a fragment identifier in its `href` attribute. If it does, we'll use that to fetch the matching link.

We'll use `find_next` instead of `find`, because the latter will fetch a matching tag from anywhere in the document, whereas `find_next` will only try to find from the position of the object being processed. I'll make it clearer with an example:

```
some_link['href']
# ../Text/chapter.xhtml#rfn1

some_link.find('a', {'id': 'rfn1'})
# <a id="rfn1" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#fn1" role="doc-backlink">1.</a>
```

If we use `find` we can't be sure if the link found appeared before the original link or after that. However, if we use `find_next`...

```
footnote_link = some_link.find_next('a', {'id': 'rfn1'})
footnote_link
# <a id="rfn1" href="../Text/chapter.xhtml#fn1" role="doc-backlink">1.</a>

footnote_link.find_next('a', {'id': 'fn1'})
# None
```

... we can be sure that this link was appeared second (and hence a footnote), because `find_next` will return `None` if it can't find a match, starting from the position of the object on which we call `find_next`.

Here's what the full code will probably look like:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    try:
        fragment_id = link['href'].rsplit('#', maxsplit=1)[1]
    except IndexError:
        # the `rsplit` returned only one string, meaning '#' wasn't found in the string
        continue

    footnote = link.find_next('a', {'id': fragment_id})
    if footnote:
        # a matching footnote has been found
        # you can add attributes to it by modifying `footnote`
```

Comment: Thanks for much for your help which has given me a good starting point. I'm getting the following error: fragment_id = link.rsplit('#', maxsplit=1)[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable... As I understand this is because it's a tag object not a string. Is there a way of getting around this? Again, thanks so much.

Comment: It also didn't work when I tried wrapping it in str()... possibly because find_next is being used later on?

Comment: Yeah, it's tag object. That was a mistake. Use `link['href'].rsplit`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have another question (sorry). I'm trying to refine the conditions. Currently links which link forward to divs with the same ID are being mislabelled as backlinks, because there isn't an anchor tag coming after it. Using link.find_next('div', {'id': fragment_id}) isn't working.

Comment: @Zai I'm afraid I won't be able to help without more details. May be, consider creating a new question with the new problem, and please include more code (the logic as well as the input - this time, specifically those inputs for which you're getting the buggy results). If you feel the code is too large, try using a (free) service like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) to paste the code there and link it here (preferably in a new question).